# Android 12 to Android 13 xamarin.android intent not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am experiencing an issue when running a xamarin.android app I made on android 12 when I run it on android 13.
The app launches Marvel Unlimited on a specific comic using an intent.

On android 12 this works perfectly, but on android 13 it gives me this error:

```
Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: 'Unable to find explicit activity class {com.marvel.unlimited/com.disney.bootstrap.activity.bootstrap.BootstrapActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?'
```

in this part of the code:

```
Android.Content.Intent targetAppIntent = context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(MarvelUnlimitedPackage);
if (targetAppIntent != null)
{
    // isread change to 1
    ComicListAdapter.UpdateIsReadStatus(item.Id, true);
    if (item.ReadUrl != null && item.ReadUrl.Length > 0)
    {
        
        targetAppIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        targetAppIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(item.ReadUrl));
        
        context.StartActivity(targetAppIntent);
    }
}
else
{
    Toast.MakeText(context, "something went wrong, is MU installed?", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

If I comment out the addflags and setdata line the marvel unlimited app opens.

Comment: Did you download the latest updates to Android 13?  I just got  new Android 13 and had to download updates to get machine to work properly.

Comment: All the updates are downloaded, but it still gives an error

Comment: Can't help.  I just bought a Samsung Galaxy A54 (Android 13) and cannot use the Burger King App.  The phone is setup to automatically connect to my GMAIL.  When I try to configure BK to use gmail it give me an error duplicate account. So I use my Office 365 email and when I order in restaurant I have to go home to get the security code on 365 before I can order.